# What scriptures did people follow before Dwapara Yuga?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, yuga

Bhagavad Gita was told by Krishna to Arjuna in Dwapara Yuga. Since then Bhagavad Gita is followed by many and is an important scripture.

But what did the people follow before Dwapara Yuga when the Bhagavad Gita wasn't there?

Comment: There were/are Dharmashastras, Smritis, Upanishads and Vedas...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What did the people follow before Dwapara Yuga when the Bhagavad Gita wasn't there?**

It is not that the Bhagavad Gita was invented by Krishna 5,000 years ago when He spoke it to Arjuna.

Bhagavad Gita 4.1 - 4.2

> श्रीभगवानुवाच
> इमं विवस्वते योगं प्रोक्तवानहमव्ययम् । विवस्वान्मनवे प्राह मनुरिक्ष्वाकवेऽब्रवीत् ॥४-१॥
>
> एवं परम्पराप्राप्तमिमं राजर्षयो विदुः । स कालेनेह महता योगो नष्टः परन्तप ॥४-२॥
>
> Krishna says: “I instructed this imperishable science of yoga to the sun-god, Vivasvan, and Vivasvan instructed it to Manu, the father of mankind, and Manu in turn instructed it to Iksvaku. The supreme science was thus received through the chain of disciplic succession, and the saintly kings understood it in that way. But in course of time the succession was broken, and therefore the science as it is appears to be lost.”

So Bhagavad Gita was there even before Dwapara yuga.

**What scriptures did people follow before Dwapara Yuga?**

In every Dwapara yuga, a Vedvyas emerged and divide **Vedas** but that doesn't mean there were no Vedas before that. Similarly, **Bhagavad Gita** (probably with different name) was also there. Ramayana happened before Dwapara yuga, so **Ramayana** was there, few Puranas depict that Yashoda used to worship Lord Shri Rama. Few other scriptures related to Lord Shiva must have been there as few Puranas say that Nand and other vrajvashi performed **Shivaratri** vrat.